# Keep getting error 'Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function web3.js

Tags: web3js

I keep getting the same error saying

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (inpage.js:1)
    at u.validateArgs (inpage.js:1)
    at u.toPayload (inpage.js:1)
    at u.call (inpage.js:1)
    at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
    at gitter.js:21
```

this is the javascript code, it seems like the contract is not being loaded correctly, because also when I console log myAccount it returns undefined..

This is the javascript

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/<token>"));
}

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/<token>"));
// web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var tokenContract = web3.eth.contract(human_standard_token_abi);
var tokenRunning = tokenContract.at('0x5780a5928becc986edd597991a1a1af6357fdf05');

var myAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

if(!web3.isConnected()) {

  alert ('not connected');

} else {

  console.log('Balance of ' + myAccount + ' is equal to ' + tokenRunning.balanceOf(myAccount).toNumber() + ' tokens');
  // console.log(myAccount);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there seem to be an issue with the account. You are using:

`var myAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];`

Instead, you should do:

```
var accounts 
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err,result){
    if(!err){
        accounts = result;
    }
});

var myAccount = accounts[0];
```

Hope this helps

UPDATE:

Getting the value from the contract:

```
var tokenContract = web3.eth.contract(human_standard_token_abi);
var tokenRunning = tokenContract.at('0x5780a5928becc986edd597991a1a1af6357fdf05');
tokenRunning.balanceOf(myAccount,function(err,result){
    if(!err){
        console.log(result)
    }
})
```

If the result is a "BigNumber" you can transform to string using result.toString(10)

Hope this helps

Comment: I get an error saying 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined when I do it this way

Comment: you are right, I updated the code. However, what version of web3 are you using?. what you did actually works in 0.14 but i think it doesn't work in 1.0. this should work in both. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'm using 0.20.1 I think, loading it over https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@0.20.1/dist/web3.min.js. The code still doesn't seem to work.. I'm getting an undefined result

Comment: then the problem is not that the account is not correct. I have a website that does what you are doing and I am also using web3. Take a look at the update on the answer. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Still not working, but I actually found a way to integrate it into the form I was already building, and there it works!

Comment: I am glad you solved it. Good luck.